# Conversion of seconds to nanoseconds in timestamp and represent using signed integer

Tags: c, if-statement, timestamp

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef unsigned short int uint16;

typedef signed short int sint32;

#define MAX_NS 999999999
#define MAX_S  4294967295

typedef struct
{
   sint64 nanoseconds;  
   sint64 seconds; 
}TimeStampType;

TimeStampType timeStamp;

sint32 timeStampDifference;

 void GetTimeStamp(sint32* timeStampDifference)
{
        /* Since the range of signed int32 (sint32) is -2147483647 to        +2147483647 timestamp values can not be represented if it exceeds 3 seconds 
 or 2 seconds and 147483647 nanoseconds */

    if((timeStamp.seconds > 3)||(timeStamp.seconds < -3)||((timeStamp.seconds == 2)&&(timeStamp.nanoseconds > 147483647))||((timestamp.seconds == -2)&&(timeStamp.nanoseconds< -147483647))){

        printf("TimeStamp value can not be represented since it overflows");    
    }

    else{

        *timeStampDifference = ((timeStamp.seconds)*(MAX_NS+1)
                         +(timeStamp.nanoseconds));
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do is,in the GetTimeStamp function I have to convert seconds value of timestamp to nanoseconds.But since `timeStampDifference` is a `sint32` parameter,it can hold only the values in the range -2147483647 to +2147483647.So nanoseconds can only be in the mentioned range after converting seconds to nanseconds.

So I am printing "TimeStamp value can not be represented since it overflows" if it exceeds the value. But I am not getting expected output.

Is the Logic written for function GetTimeStamp correct?What are the ways to improve the functionality of GetTimeStamp function.

I have edited the question as per the comments.Kindly help anyone,I have a high stake on this.

(Since 1 second equals 1e+9 nanoseconds,which means the max seconds value can be  2.147483647 seconds.I will not consider secondsUp at all ,since 1 secondsUp equals 4294967296 seconds)

Comment: I don't really see why you are doing this? I mean why are you using nanoseconds to begin with? If you really have to why don't you consider using seconds/ milliseconds and rounding the nanoseconds respectively

Comment: Too many global variables.  Setting `timeStampDifference = 0;` repeatedly is odd.  The `secondsUp` member should be omitted from the code to make an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: A 16-bit integer like the `sint16 timeStampDifference` can't hold nanoseconds-worth of difference.  It needs to be `sint32` if not `sint64`.

Comment: Why can't the difference be represented as seconds + nanoseconds just like the timestamps?

Comment: As @JonathanLeffler wrote, the comment inside the function is wrong and misleading, since the parameter is 16-bit. But anyway, whatever you are trying to do doesn't make any sense. Just have a single `struct { u32 unixtime; u32 nanoseconds; }` and don't do these silly conversions. The `secondsUp` field is poorly named and redundant; if you are afraid of unix time overflow in 2106 (if using unsigned unix timestamp), simply use `u64` for the seconds.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the comments. timeStampDifference is sint32.It was a typo error.I have corrected it.I know that some parts of the code is redundant but my doubt is how to convert seconds to nanoseconds with the constraints I have mentioned.I am concentrating just on GetTimeStamp function.How to avoid overflow,without the loss of values.

Comment: @meow Thanks for your insight.But the requirement is to provide the difference in nanoseconds.How can I convert seconds to nanoseconds with considering overflows.

Comment: `if((timeStamp.secondsUp > 0)||(timeStamp.seconds > 3)

||((timeStamp.seconds == 2)&&(timeStamp.nanoseconds > 147483647))){` is certainly wrong.  I'd expect `... (timeStamp.seconds >= 3 ...` (`>=` vs `>`)

Comment: @chux seconds can not be equal to 3 , because I can not represent 3seconds in sint32 parameter. the range is  -2147483647 to +2147483647.Since 1 second equals 1e+9 nanoseconds,then the seconds value can be in the range -2.147483647 to +2.147483647

Comment: An easy test would be `int64_t ns =((timeStamp.seconds)*(MAX_NS+1LL)
                         +(timeStamp.nanoseconds)); if (ns < INT16_MIN || ns > INT16_MAX) { printf("TimeStamp value can not be represented ..."); } else { *timeStampDifference = ns; }`

Comment: @GopalaKrishna  "since timeStampDifference is a sint32 parameter," and code `sint16* timeStampDifference` conflict.  Post is unclear.

Comment: @chux thanks for the reply .Instead of INT16_x it should be INT32_x right?Oh..ya . I have edited the question now. Is there a way so that to check for overflow without using additional variables?Please help me.

Comment: @GopalaKrishna the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825394/conversion-of-seconds-to-nanoseconds-in-timestamp-and-represent-using-signed-int#comment78648883_45825394) "Instead of INT16_MIN it should be INT16_MIN" does not make sense. It reads like "Instead of XXX it should be XXX".

Comment: @GopalaKrishna "Is there a way so that to check for overflow without using additional variables" --> sure, but this post keeps changing.  A moving target is hard to answer with its morphing of sign-ness, width and non-standard type names.

Comment: @chux No there are no more changes .kindly help

Comment: @chux in timestamp, the second value can be negative also.What all changes can be made

Comment: @GopalaKrishna `uint32 seconds;` is never negative as it is unsigned so [second value can be negative also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45825394/conversion-of-seconds-to-nanoseconds-in-timestamp-and-represent-using-signed-int?noredirect=1#comment78649683_45825394) is not true.

Comment: @chux i never looked it that way.I have edited the question.Can you please provide any hints now.(Appologies for changing the question so many times):)

Comment: I suggest you 1) _carefully_ re-think the question, types, sign-ness, etc. needed 2)  delete this post and 3) tomorrow post a new, well thought out, question with details, examples and code that compiles/runs.

Comment: Considered this again, it just makes NO SENSE. If you really want to go this utterly silly way, you should understand what happens on the bit level. You can obviously check for the MAX_INT value but cannot know whether it is just this or actually higher without either doing the arithmetic or using a larger unit. But anyways nanseconds and sint32 is probably just a very very very bad idea, which you should circumvent if anyhow possible.

Comment: @chux I have rethought and made all the possible changes in my question.I thought of reposting my question but I am not able to since my question got downvotes.So i have edited in this post only.Can you please have a look and tell me how it can be done?Please I have a high stake on this.

Comment: @meow Can you please have a look now?

Answer (score 1):

The question comes down to `seconds*1000000000 + ns` and will it overflow?

```
#define NS_PER_SEC 1000000000 

int64_t sum_s_ns(int64_t s, int64_t ns) {
  if (s > INT64_MAX/NS_PER_SEC || s < INT64_MIN/NS_PER_SEC) {
    fail_overflow();
    return 0;
  } 
  s *= NS_PER_SEC;
  if (s < 0) {
    // if s + ns < min
    if (ns < INT64_MIN - s) {
      fail_overflow();
      return 0;
    } 
  } else {
    // if s + ns > max
    if (ns > INT64_MAX - s) {
      fail_overflow();
      return 0;
    } 
  }
  return s + ns;
}
```

See [Test if arithmetic operation will cause undefined behavior](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93699/29485)

Comment: Thanks a lot man..You saved me.I am so thankful for the time you took to help me. You're a wonderful person,I want you to know that